# Oracle sql case statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need some help with case statement.
my code:

```
select c.name, c.date_entered, i.transaction, i.planned_date,
case (c.date_entered - i.planned_date)
when (c.date_entered - i.planned_date) > 0 then 'YES'
when (c.date_entered - i.planned_date) < 0 then 'NO'
end RESPECT
from company c,transaction i
```

but it give me error ORA-00907; missing right parenthesis

thank you to help me with.

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement. (It returns a value.)

Comment: Don't you need a join condition?

Comment: hello , yes I have inner join there. Please what is different between case exprassion and case statement?

Comment: Without a join condition you get a `cross join`, i.e. the cartesian product!

Comment: A case expression returns a value, and is typicallty used as a part of a SQL statement. A case statement has no return value, and is used for conditional execution of code (for example in a stored procedure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select c.name, c.date_entered, i.transaction, i.planned_date,
       case when c.date_entered - i.planned_date > 0 
            then 'YES'
            when c.date_entered - i.planned_date < 0 
            then 'NO'
       end as RESPECT
from company c, transaction i
```

You should also think about the output of `when c.date_entered - i.planned_date = 0` or change one of the cases to `<=` or  `>=`.

Comment: Hello thank you very much, it works for me. thak you.